# Error: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:371:5)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I try to create a new user on my application. it inserts to the database when am testing on postman, this is the code below

```
import { Request, Response } from "express";
import logger from "../utils/logger";
import { createUser } from "../service/user.service";
import { CreateUserInput } from "../schema/user.schema";
import { omit } from "lodash";

export async function createUserHandler(
  req: Request<{}, {}, CreateUserInput["body"]>,
  res: Response
) {
  try {
    const user = await createUser(req.body);
    return res.send(user);
  } catch (error: any) {
    logger.error(error);
    return res.status(409).send(error.message);
  }
}
```

this is the error am getting when i use the route. On postman am gettin 404, Cannot POST /api/users

````
{"level":50, "time": 2023-05-15T11:27:36+01:00,"pid":false,"err":{"type":"Error","message":"Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client","stack":"Error: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client\n    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:371:5)\n    at ServerResponse.setHeader (node:_http_outgoing:576:11)\n    at ServerResponse.header (/[Folder directory]/backend_d1motors/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:794:10)\n    at ServerResponse.send (/[Folder directory]/backend_d1motors/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:174:12)\n    at ServerResponse.json (/[Folder directory]/backend_d1motors/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:278:15)\n    at ServerResponse.send (/[Folder directory]/backend_d1motors/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:162:21)\n    at /[Folder directory]/backend_d1motors/src/controller/user.controller.ts:13:16\n    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)\n    at fulfilled (/[Folder directory]/backend_d1motors/src/controller/user.controller.ts:5:58)\n    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)","code":"ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT"},"msg":"Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client"}
Error: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:371:5)
    at ServerResponse.setHeader (node:_http_outgoing:576:11)
    at ServerResponse.header (/[Folder directory]/backend_d1motors/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:794:10)
    at ServerResponse.send (/[Folder directory]/backend_d1motors/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:174:12)
    at /[Folder directory]/backend_d1motors/src/controller/user.controller.ts:16:28
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at fulfilled (/[Folder directory]/backend_d1motors/src/controller/user.controller.ts:5:58)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
[ERROR] 11:27:36 Error: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client```
````

Comment: Can you show the code of `user.controller.ts` file?

Comment: @LinDu thats the code above

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7042340/error-cant-set-headers-after-they-are-sent-to-the-client

Answer (score 0):

The issue issue is because of having the `res.send()` function in try block.
When there's a condition of `error`, the try block will execute and when it's the time of error, it will execute the code without breaking the execution flow.

try removing `res.send` function from the try block and keep it outside of try-catch block.